# if row is missing, data == 0. if not missing use default value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv')
    a = df.loc['a'].sum()
    b = df.loc['b'].sum()
    c = df.loc['c'].sum()
    d = (a + b) / c
    return d
```

in some dataframes there is no row 'b', so it returns KeyError. Then I tried following code, but it doesnt work, anyone can help me provide a solution to this problem?

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv')
    a = df.loc['a'].sum()
    if df.loc['b'].isnull():
        b == 0
    else:
        b = df.loc['b'].sum()
    c = df.loc['c'].sum()
    d = (a + b) / c
    return d
```

Comment: df.loc['b].isnull checks if the value in the row 'b' is null/NaN and not if the row b exists or not . To check if the row with index 'b' exists :-  if 'b' in df.index

Comment: `b = df.loc['b'].sub() if 'b' in df else 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv')
    
    if b in df.columns: #Check if column b exists.
        b = df.loc['b'].sum()
    else:
        b = 0

    a = df.loc['a'].sum()
    c = df.loc['c'].sum()
    d = (a + b) / c
    return d
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond it worked, however I have a follow up question. why did you define 'b' in df.columns? shouldnt 'b' be a row?

Comment: @StockJanitor For your question, when you `read_csv`, by default, `header="infer"`, which will cause your row of `A`, `B`, `C` as a header/column_name. So it returns `KeyError` when the column is not found. Hope that answers your question. Do approve the solution too! :)

Comment: Ohh i see thank you, is thtere a button for me to click approve solution? im new in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add not exist values `a` or `b` or `c` rows, also in `df` are only 3 filtered rows only:

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv').reindex(['a','b','c'], fill_value=0)
    a = df.loc['a'].sum()
    b = df.loc['b'].sum()
    c = df.loc['c'].sum()
    d = (a + b) / c
    return d
```

If use same function 3 times is possible use `sum` per `axis=1`:

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv').reindex(['a','b','c'], fill_value=0)
    abc = df.sum(axis=1)

    a = abc.loc['a']
    b = abc.loc['b']
    c = abc.loc['c']
    d = (a + b) / c
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:-

```
def compute(tick):
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{tick}.csv')
    a = df.loc['a'].sum()
    c = df.loc['c'].sum()
    try:
       return(a + df.loc['b'].sum()) / c
    except KeyError:
       pass
    return a / c
```

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly :D